# An example of a square matrix with the same eigenvectors but different eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there an example such that $A$ and $B$, three by three, that have the same eigenvectors, but different eigenvalues?

What would be the eigenvectors and eigenvalues if it exists because I'm stuck on this practice problem.

I know that if matrices $A$ and $B$ can be written such that $AB=BA$, they share the same eigenvectors, but what about their eigenvalues? precisely if they're squared matrices ($3\times 3$ case)

Answer (score 4):

How about $I$ and $-I$?  Then all $x\neq0$ are eigenvectors.   But the eigenvalues are $1$ and $-1$ respectively.

For a less trivial example,  how about $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}4&0&0\\0&3&1\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$?

They share eigenvectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, but for different eigenvalues.

As to your question about commuting matrices, you could take any two diagonal matrices, with different entries on the respective diagonals.

Comment: It only works for the identity matrices?

Comment: Hmm.  I'll have to think about it.   It looks like multiples of identity matrices will work.  How about a permutation matrix?

Comment: It would work if you put different values on the diagonal.   Maybe using Jordan normal form we can make examples.